# Using Selenium IDE's getEval command with FirefoxWebdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Hello,

I have a working Selenium IDE script that is working using this code:

```
 getEval |      this.page().findElement('xpath=//html/body/div[18]/div[9]/div[2]/div/div[9]/div[2]/center/div/div/div[2]/div/span/span/a').removeAttribute('target')
```

I then exported the entire test case as a Junit test case.  The command for the getEval was not included with the export.  I tried the following code:

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

}
js.executeScript("this.page().findElement('xpath=//html/body/div[18]/div[9]/div[2]/div/div[9]/div[2]/center/div/div/div[2]/div/span/span/a').removeAttribute('target');");
```

When running this line of code, I get and exception: page is not defined

I have also tried:

```
sel = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl());
    sel.getEval("page().findElement('xpath=//html/body/div[18]/div[9]/div[2]/div/div[9]/div[2]/center/div/div/div[2]/div/span/span/a').removeAttribute('target')");
```

The Junit test crashes when this line in ran, and the test case fails.  I was wondering if I am sending the correct javascript script or if there is another, better, way of doing such a Selenium command through java.

I am using java 6 and Selenium 2.33.0

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try selenium webdriver API or selenium 2.0 ? It is a better way if you want to write more complicated tests. You can see some examples here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#selenium-webdriver-api-commands-and-operations